# Using authorize tag for jwt token validation

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi, okta

I have recently integrated with okta on my front end using a SPA application and then also a seperate API application in okta for authorization in my asp.net core web api. I use access tokens to pass from the front end spa to the backend web api. I followed this short tutorial to setup local jwt token validation:

https://developer.okta.com/blog/2022/04/20/dotnet-6-web-api

I am not a fan of adding a million if statements checking the token validation in the every api method of my controllers. Before using okta and instead using identity framework by .net core I could use the [authorize] tag in my controller at a global level or at a method level. This even worked when I used azure ad as well for authentication. This was super convenient and I’m curious if this can easily be added to the implementation of that tutorial via the program.cs file like I did in the past (I can post my code here but it’s identical to his) or do I need to build out a custom authorize filter myself?

Edit!!

My current approach so far:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using API.Okta;

namespace API.Filters
{
    public class OktaAuthorizeFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        private readonly Okta.IJwtValidator _validationService;

        public OktaAuthorizeFilter(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, IJwtValidator validationService)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            _validationService = validationService;
        }

        public async void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            var authToken = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext!.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(authToken))
            {
                context.Result = new UnauthorizedObjectResult(string.Empty);
                return;
            }

            var validatedToken = await _validationService.ValidateToken(authToken.Split(" ")[1]);

            if (validatedToken == null)
            {
                context.Result = new UnauthorizedObjectResult(string.Empty);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public class OktaAuthorizeAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
    {
        public OktaAuthorizeAttribute() : base(typeof(OktaAuthorizeFilter))
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your link, the verification of `Token` is actually done in `IJwtValidator`, and the controller just checks whether it is empty. You can create a custom middleware, inject `IJwtValidator`, and then check whether it is empty directly in the middleware.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to build a custom middelware. For more information, see: https://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-core/custom-middleware-aspnetcore. Anyways, here is a quick example.

**Note that you might have to change the implemenation of `InvokeAsync()`**

```
public class MyAuthMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
 
    public CustomAuthMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }
 
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        string authHeader = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
        if (authHeader != null && authHeader.StartsWith("Bearer"))
        {
            string token = authHeader.Substring("Bearer ".Length).Trim();
 
            try
            {
                // Validate the token
                var claimsPrincipal = ValidateToken(token);
                context.User = claimsPrincipal;
            }
            catch
            {
                // Return unauthorized status code if the token is invalid
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                return;
            }
        }
 
        await _next(context);
    }
 
    private ClaimsPrincipal ValidateToken(string token)
    {
        // Implement validation logic here
    }
}
```

Then you can simply use this middelware in the `Program.cs`, which will then authenticate the incoming requests automatically.

```
app.UseMiddleware<MyAuthMiddelware>();
```

Comment: I updated my question to include my current approach. Is this approach better or worse than yours using a middlewear?

Comment: @IrishRedneck Using a filter you would need to decorate the controller or endpoint, which needs to be authorized. Commonly you would make use of a middelware, but a filter would work aswell.